# how to upgrade jboss 4.0.3sp1 to 5.1?

Tags: jboss, upgrade

i mean i just want to upgrade jboss application server from 4.0.3sp1 to 5.1, i have downloaded jboss-5.1.0.GA.zip, but i have not found any procedures from internet, is there any official upgrade procedures or guides, commands about this upgrade?

otherwise, i just need to unzip jboss-5.1.0.GA.zip, and copy *.ear, *.war from old jboss direcotry to the new version 5.1? but which configuration files should be modified manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you shouldn't have to change anything - just copy your EARs and WARs across, and off you go.

In practice, it may not be that simple, there are a bunch of minor differences in how they interpret the JavaEE spec (JBoss5 is generally stricter). However, all I can advise is that you give it a try, and address each problem as it arises.